# Как отсортировать массив в PHP?

Tags: php, сортировка

Есть массив:

```
$array[0]= '5';
$array[1]= '3';
$array[2]= '2';
$array[3]= '1';
$array[4]= '14';
```

Как отсортировать его значения что-бы стало так:

```
$array[0]= '1';
$array[1]= '2';
$array[2]= '3';
$array[3]= '5';
$array[4]= '14';
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что rtfm

Comment: @PinkTux никогда не понимал таких личностей :) им проще зарегаться на сайте и написать целый вопрос, вместо того, что бы написать в гугл sort array php и в первой же ссылке увидеть исчерпывающую информацию по этому вопросу: http://php.net/manual/ru/array.sorting.php

Comment: всем возмущающимся (и минусующим ответы) предлагаю ознакомиться, например, с этим обсуждением: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616/178576)

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что тут сортируются строки, по их численному значению?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский наличие ответа в мануалах никак не влияет на соответствие теме.

Comment: @Etki это у вас не влияет, а у меня все по пунктикам расписано. Так что всё влияет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вам бы логику преподавать

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае поможет функция

```
sort($array);
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sort.php

В качестве первого аргумента эта функция принимает массив и сортирует его.
Новый массив будет записан вместо старого(здесь передача аргумента по ссылке).

Comment: А то что в вопросе надо отсортировать по числовым значениям, ваш ответ учитывает?

Answer (score -2):

Вот:

```
$array= array("1", "2", "3", "4");
sort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    echo "array[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: добавь описание почему именно эти флаги нужны